# Does firebase datasnapshot download the data when we invoke getValue?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does firebase datasnapshot download the data when we invoke getValue 
or does it behave more like a container that contains the whole tree structure referenced in database reference?

I need to perform an Or operation but according to the documentation that's not allowed. So I figured  I would download the data I need from the narrowest node, and perform the filtering locally. The problem is that even then the data might eventually grow large if I have to download all of it and filter locally. So, if datasnapshot downloads the data when we invoke get value I could safely ignore the need to make a complex query to firebase.

Answer (score 1):

When you call getValue, then entire contents of the node is downloaded and becomes available.  In that sense, there are no "shallow" queries exposed by the mobile client SDKs.  (Though the REST API does support shallow queries that don't download all the child nodes.)

As you've identified, this can change the way that you might want to organize your data.  Shallow data structures are typically preferred in Realtime Database for this reason.